# Reading local excel file in browser with read-excel-file.js

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, web-frontend

I'm trying to create an html table that is based on data coming in from an excel sheet. I plan on using a javascript script to convert the excel data into an html table using read-excel-data.js. I have the excel sheet locally, but am not sure how to send the excel file with the html/js/css to the browser. So in my javascript file when I try to call readXlsxFile("data.xlsx"), data.xlsx is not found because it does not exist within the browser. Is there a way for me to send data.xlsx to the browser without having to manually upload with an `input type="file"` element?

Comment: You have some Excel sheets and you want to use these to automatically generate html tables on a web page?  What is the source of the Excel files, how many files, and how often do they change?  May the conversion be done on the backend or only on the client? The question doesn't provide enough detail to suggest a good solution.

Comment: From your setup, it's not possible. The browser would either have to get the file from user input (input type file you mentioned), or to obtain it from an AJAX call. For example, you could serve the Excel files from Google Drive, or have all of your Excel files within a folder on your computer, which you would automatically sync with Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

For obvious security reasons, the browser should not allow this at all except in the case of a user action, such as `file input`. In fact, think what implications it would have if a Web site could explore and read/write data from the file system on which it is running.

You can only directly receive files from agents such as web servers or similar applications via functions such as `fetch(...)`